# using UserPart based Parts in testing

Tags: c#, unit-testing, orchardcms

I'm writing some tests for data mapping that takes a ContentItem that has as part of it a UserPart. When I try to use it in my unit tests I and assign the email property I get InfoSet errors. How do I go about mocking up things so that the InfoSet will properly be filled in absent a database?

When attempted using Bertrand's ContentHelpers, as soon as I try to set UserPart's Email property I receive the following:

> System.Reflection.TargetException occurred   HResult=-2146232829
>   Message=**Non-static method requires a target.**   Source=mscorlib
>   StackTrace:
>          at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.CheckConsistency(Object target)
>          at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InvokeArgumentsCheck(Object obj,
>   BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters,
>   CultureInfo culture)
>          at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters,
>   CultureInfo culture)
>          at System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.SetValue(Object obj, Object value, Object[] index)
>          at Orchard.ContentManagement.InfosetHelper.Store[TPart,TRecord,TProperty](TPart
>   contentPart, Expression`1 targetExpression, TProperty value) in
>   .....Orchard.Source.1.8\src\Orchard\ContentManagement\InfosetHelper.cs:line
>   122   InnerException:

Example of usage:

```
        ContentItem usrItem = ContentHelpers.PreparePart(new UserPart(), "User") ;
        UserPart usrPart = usrItem.As<UserPart>();
        usrPart.Email = "test@tester.com";
```

Link to Bertrand's Blog Post showing ContentHelpers: http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/faking-orchard-content-items-for-testing

Comment: That's weird, it looks like the record is null. Can you attach a debugger and check that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Bertrand Le Roy suggested in his comment, the record is null.

You are constructing your content item like this:

```
ContentItem usrItem = ContentHelpers.PreparePart(new UserPart(), "User");
```

If you compare that to the way Bertrand describes the process in his Blog, you'll notice that in addition to creating a `BodyPart`, he is also creating it's underlying `BodyPartRecord`.  This is required because data backed `Parts`, like the `BodyPart` and `UserPart` delegate most of their functionality down to the underlying `PartRecord`.

To fix your problem, you just need to change the way you construct your content item to include the construction of the underlying record:

```
ContentItem usrItem = ContentHelpers.PreparePart(new UserPart { 
                                                     Record = new UserPartRecord() 
                                                 }, "User");
```

Comment: Thanks! That seems to work fine. Sorry about missing that point.